# How to play and stream RTMP for iOS in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rtmp, live-streaming

I'm looking to build an app which plays and streams RTMP media.

#### Playback

What's a recommended library that supports RTMP playback? I can't seem to find a good one.

#### Streaming

I've tried the demo from https://github.com/shogo4405/lf.swift, but can't get it to stream to an RTMP server. Are there any other recommended libraries, preferably in Swift?

Note: The reason for using RTMP over HLS is the better latency.

Comment: Library requests are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-I-implement-RTMP-playing-and-streaming-for-iOS-Swift?srid=tWlR